# Не могу понять этот код

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, пузырьковая-сортировка

Я изучал алгоритмы сортировки. И для учёбы начал с сортировки пузырьком. Нашёл программный код этого алгоритма, но не смог понять 3-ую строку.
Не можете ли вы объяснить этот программный код?

```
let arr=[2,1,3,5,4];
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     for(let j=0;j<arr.length-i;j++){
         if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
            let tmp=arr[i];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=tmp;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: А что вас смущает в третьей строке, если вторая понятна?

Comment: Именно j<arr.length-i

Comment: Внутренний цикл будет идти не до конца массива, а на i элементов меньше (поскольку i элементов в конце уже стоят на своих окончательных местах, их проверять не надо)

Comment: Как сделать ваш комментарии ответом?

Comment: Сделал ответ....

Comment: Спасибо, помогли :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутренний цикл будет идти не до конца массива, а на `i` элементов меньше.

Поскольку на `i`-м шаге внешнего цикла `i` элементов в конце уже стоят на своих окончательных местах, их проверять не надо.

Answer (score 0):

И в этом коде ошибка - выход за пределы массива. Эта строка должна быть такой - `j<arr.length-i-1`, т.к. [j]-ый элемент сравнивается с [j+1]-ым. А потом идет обмен значениями:

```
for(let j=0; j<arr.length-i-1; j++)
```

По просьбе Scetch - на первой итерации `i==0`. Второй (внутренний) цикл идет до `j<arr.length`. Допустим размер массива - 5. Тогда `j` будет идти от 0 до 4. И вот на последнем шаге, когда `j==4` будет производиться операция доступа к элементу `arr[j+1]`, т.е. к `arr[5]` - которого не существует, это выход за пределы массива. UB - неопределенное поведение

```
if(arr[4] > arr[5])
{
   let tmp=arr[4];
   arr[4]=arr[5];
   arr[5]=tmp;
}
```

Comment: А можно подробнее

Comment: Так код исправления же дан

Comment: Добавил в ответ подробное пояснение.